# Assign read & write file permission to a specific user for a specific file using php

Tags: php, macos, unix, permissions, chmod

I want to change file permission for a particular user for a specific file .
All these things needs to be done by php.
I am using `chmod(file_path, 0644)`. 
But its not working.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

missing "$" ?

`chmod($file_path, 0644)`

or no permission because not owner of $file_path (apache-php runs as user wwwrun)

Comment: Thats fine . I just added file_path for demonstration purpose.

Do you know how to change file permission of other user in php?